# Any WinINet and WinHTTP implementation in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, http, networking

I was reading about WinINet vs. WinHTTP and came to know that -

1. **WinINet** was designed as an HTTP API client platform that allowed the
   use of interactive message dialogs such as entering user credentials
   it's able to handle HTTP and FTP protocols.
2. **WinHTTP**'s API set is geared towards a non-interactive environment
       allowing for use in service-based applications where no user
       interaction is required or needed, and is also much faster than
       WinINet - it only handles HTTP protocol.

However in .NET I generally use `HttpClient` class for HTTP communications. I wish to know: are there specific classes in .NET targeting different use cases like we have in- WinINet vs WinHTTP?
Are .NET classes built over WinINet/WinHTTP or they directly use sockets?

Comment: WinINet and WinHTTP both predate the .NET environment by many years. There should be little reason to use them from .NET though you probably could with a bit of effort. The networking classes in .NET, HttpClient among them, do not rely on WinINet or WinHTTP.

Comment: little reason? winhttp is implemented in kernel mode and blazing fast.

Answer (score 1):

Probably youve found that yourself but here is the link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.winhttphandler?view=dotnet-plat-ext-2.1